# Android setOnClickListener method - How does it work?

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have trouble understanding this code. I get that `findViewById` will get the button widget and then it'll cast it. Then, it's going to use the button to call the `setOnClickListener` method. However, I don't know what is that argument being passed into the `setOnClickListener` and I have never seen code like that before. How is it that it creates a new object but is able to create a method of its own within another method's argument? Would be great if someone could explain that. Also, what type of object is the `setOnClickListener` method taking in?

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.firstButton);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        tv.setText(months[rand.nextInt(12)]);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(rand.nextInt(255)+1, rand.nextInt(255)+1, rand.nextInt(255)+1));
    }
});
```

Comment: put inside the toat and check

Comment: It's providing an instance of an anonymous class that conforms to the interface View.OnClickListener.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It works like this. View.OnClickListenere is defined -

```
public interface OnClickListener {
    void onClick(View v);
}
```

As far as we know you cannot instantiate an object `OnClickListener`, as it doesn't have a method implemented. So there are two ways you can go by - you can implement this interface which will override `onClick` method like this:

```
public class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
         // your code here;
    }
}
```

But it's tedious to do it each time as you want to set a click listener. So in order to avoid this you can provide the implementation for the method on spot, just like in an example you gave.

`setOnClickListener` takes `View.OnClickListener` as its parameter.

Comment: Awesome explanation!! Makes perfect sense now and learned something new!! I never knew you can instantiate an object of an interface by implementing its method on the spot. Very cool.

Comment: If you want to know more read about Observer Design Pattern :)

Answer (score 13):

This is the best way to implement Onclicklistener for many buttons in a row
implement View.onclicklistener.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

This is a button in the MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bt_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

    bt_submit.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

This is an override method

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.submit:
                //action

                break;

            case R.id.secondbutton:
                //action
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: MainActivity cannot be converted to OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

That what manual [says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) about `setOnClickListener` method is:

```
public void setOnClickListener (View.OnClickListener l)
```

> Added in API level 1 Register a callback to be invoked when this view
>   is clicked. If this view is not clickable, it becomes clickable.

**Parameters**

> l View.OnClickListener: The callback that will run

And normally you have to use it like this

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {
        ...
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.corky);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // Implement the OnClickListener callback
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
    }
    ...
}
```

Take a look at this lesson as well [Building a Simple Calculator using Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xl1x8eazbrM&ebc=ANyPxKr7uanNpJyW2UNvdSJGe6icStfh8ACnAf-yZZDe1EbQvjhb60XEnHPj9WU_Kd7c2lbfLfRiYW09jVdQtXnRH6IwhcafSA).

Answer (score 0):

its an implementation of anonymouse class object creation to give ease of writing less code and to save time

Answer (score 0):

It works by same principle of anonymous inner class where we can instantiate an interface without actually defining a class :

Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/anonymous-inner-class-java/

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked.