# Android Studio - How to identify similar parts of (dynamically created) copies of a fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

So I have an activity in which I have multiple dynamically allocated/created copies of a Fragment:
[image]

I want to be able to set each of the times via their separate buttons, but I'm currently a little confused on how I know which button/textView I'm working with. I need to use an onClickListener (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803727/android-setonclicklistener-method-how-does-it-work)) and to use that, I would need to recognize a button (with an XML-defined ID) in code. But, `R.id.buttonID` wont work because all of those buttonID's associate with the same integer ID, so I'm not exactly sure how to uniquely recognize each of the buttons (and text views) in this case. I thought that I could maybe store the location of the fragments in an array or ordered container, but I don't think that will help in identifying each fragment's inner pieces. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

This is my XML. I'm not sure if at all how this will help, but here! My java doesn't have anything in it, otherwise I would post it.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UpcomingCycleFragment"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/upCycleFrag">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/upcomingTime"

            android:text="--:-- AM"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/upcomingDuration"

                android:text="0m long"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/upcomingEnd"

                android:text="Ends at --:--pm"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/thisbuttonsucks"

            android:text="Edit Time"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: each edit time button is a different fragment?

Comment: @lelloman Each of the horizontal blocks (containing time, duration, and button) are fragments. The XML given is for that fragment.

Comment: I see, it looks like something you would do with a RecyclerView, not fragments