# How to enter text for two textview by multiple buttons in android studio?

Tags: android

I have 9 buttons for numbers. I want to click the button and the textview will show the numbers I clicked.

Comment: Show us what have you done till now. Without seeing your code or your screenshot we can't help you. Here's a quick guide to asking questions - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

You can check this answer on this question:
[Android setOnClickListener method - How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803727/android-setonclicklistener-method-how-does-it-work)

Basically, you can create click listener on your TextView. After that, you can setText your TextView.

Comment: The OP is asking about buttons and not adding listeners to the TextView itself.