# How to switch between two custom JSON mapStyles in google map Android SDK

Tags: android, google-maps

Using google map style documentation, I have been able to create a style in JSON and use it.But I will like to switch between two custom map styles on click of a button. The button is an ImageView which I will append an onclick Listener.

*JAVA*

```
try {
            boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.mystyle.json));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }
```

*XML*

```
 <ImageView 
    android:id="@id/change_map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803727/android-setonclicklistener-method-how-does-it-work

Comment: Hi @ Emin Guliev! Thank you. I have an idea of how to use on setOnClickListener but how to switch between two map style resources in Android is the question. If you have a working sample implementation of this, you could help share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can change the map styles on the click of the button.
Just add below code:

```
boolean isMapStyleOne=false;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.change_map:{
            if(isMapStyleOne) {
                googleMap.setMapStyle(
                        MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                                requireContext(), R.raw.map_styles_1));
                isMapStyleOne=false;
            } else{
                googleMap.setMapStyle(
                        MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                                requireContext(), R.raw.map_styles_2));
                isMapStyleOne=true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works well on click of button but default style on map loaded is Google's map default.

Comment: Then write in your onMapReady method your default style for map. Like this  googleMap.setMapStyle(
                        MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                                requireContext(), R.raw.map_styles_1));

Comment: Yeah, that is my current approach using the try catch outside the setOnClickListener to load my preferred default map style. Just thought it could be different. Thank you for the help.